Error using save_kable when using library kableextra to create a table in R Quarto
I would like to save a table generated with kableExtra as a PNG file in a quarto report.
I'm using the example provided in the help file of save_kable
kable(mtcars[1:5, ], "html") %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  row_spec(1, color = "red") %>%
  save_kable('test.png')

And receive the following error

Error: rsession-utf8.exe: GeometryDoesNotContainImage `C:\test.png' @
warning/attribute.c/GetImageBoundingBox/534

I'm using R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) in RStudio with the following libraries:
kableextra 1.4
chromote 0.3.1
webshot 0.5.5
webshot2 0.1.1


getting the same error in Linux. You could probably open an issue on the package's github page

This might be from using knitr::kable() instead of the recommended kableExtra::kbl().

using kableExtra::kbl() didn't solve the problem for me.

An alternative is to first save as an html file and then use webshot2 to convert to png:
kable(mtcars[1:5, ], "html") %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  row_spec(1, color = "red") %>%
  save_kable('test.html')

webshot2::webshot("test.html", "test.png")


